# RxJava 1 and RxJava 2 in the same project

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Our project uses RxJava 1:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
```

There is a library we use that uses RxJava 2 internally:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.9'
```

When I do `./gradlew assembleDebug` I get this error:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
      File1: /Users/darklord/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.6/2586312cd2b8a511e4c6236736f5a039fc0f2273/rxjava-1.1.6.jar
      File2: /Users/darklord/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.0.9/a5aad74623ade11162dd53cdf0645a51b12221a0/rxjava-2.0.9.jar
```

I think it is said that RxJava 1 and RxJava 2 can be used at the same time, why I am still getting this error?

Comment: guess what google returns for `Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties` - a solution

Answer (score 4):

rxjava.properties file is not required at run time.

So you can exclude the file while packaging your android app by setting packagingOptions in app/build.gradle file as shown below.

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/**rxjava.properties**'
    }
}
```